# Show the content of a variable inside a html form (javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm doing a program with Javascript. I have to do some operations in this program, and, at the end, I have to show the result inside a form.

How can I do it? I think that maybe I have to put something in the "id" or "value" params, but, i'm not sure!!

Thank you!

Here I let you see some of my code. (THIS IS NOT ALL THE CODE, THIS IS ONLY THE PART THAT I THINK THAT AFFECTS in what i'm questioning)

```js
function loadPage()
{ 
 var divContent = "<br/>This is a calculator. Introcuce 2 numbers and an operator. ";
 divContent += "<input type = 'text' id='number1' value='0'/> ";
        divContent += "<input type = 'text' id='operator' value=''/> ";      
        divContent += "<input type = 'text' id='number2' value='0'/>";
 divContent += "<input type = 'button' value='operations' onclick='operations()'/>";
 
 document.getElementById("content").innerHTML += divContent;
}
 
function operations()
{
 
 var number1 = document.getElementById("number1").value; 
        var operator = document.getElementById("operator").value;
        var number2 = document.getElementById("number2").value;
 var divContent="<br><br><br> RESULT: ";
        
        switch(operator) 
        {
            case '+':
                
                result = number1 + number2;
                             
                var divContent="The result of "+ number1 +" + "+number2+" = ";
                divContent += "<input type = 'text' id='operator' value=''/>";
                break;
            }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your working code:

```js
var divContent = "<br/>This is a calculator. Introcuce 2 numbers and an operator. ";
 divContent += "<input type = 'text' id='number1' value='0'/> ";
        divContent += "<input type = 'text' id='operator' value=''/> ";      
        divContent += "<input type = 'text' id='number2' value='0'/>";
 divContent += "<input type = 'button' value='operations' onclick='operations()'/>";
 
 document.body.innerHTML += divContent;

function operations()
{
 var number1 = document.getElementById("number1").value; 
    var operator = document.getElementById("operator").value;
    var number2 = document.getElementById("number2").value;
 var divContent="<br><br><br> RESULT: ";
    document.body.innerHTML += divContent;        
        switch(operator) 
        {
            case '+':
                
                result = parseInt(number1,10) + parseInt(number2,10);
                             
                var divContent="The result of "+ number1 +" + "+number2+" = ";
                divContent += "<input type = 'text' id='operator' value='"+result+"'/>";
                document.body.innerHTML += divContent;
                break;
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In general: You can concatenate strings with `string = "..." + text;`

If you want to put the result in the new input-tag, use the following:

```
divContent += "<input type = 'text' id='operator' value='"+ result +"'/>";
```